# How do you hide part website from search engines

Tags: html, seo, hide, search-engine

I noticed that Pinterest and a few other sites allows users to select if they don't want their names to be indexed by search engines.  I want to do something similar on our site. Essentially I want to allow users that their comments on the message boards will not show up when someone searches for their name on Google/etc.

Not sure if it is relevant, but we are using Ruby on Rails.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to tell search engines that a page should only partially be indexed. You can disallow indexing (`noindex` value for `meta`-`robots` element or for HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag`) or crawling (`Disallow` in `robots.txt` file) of a *whole* page, but not of specific parts.
An exception is content that is included from an external source which itself is blocked from crawling (e.g., an `iframe` element).

Of course you could use some "hacks", e.g. to take advantage of search engines not being able (or not wanting) to index some elements or content inserted with JavaScript. But this might break at any time. Search engines will get better and might start to index such content in the future.

Possible solutions (but none without trade-offs):

- Permission system: make the postings of these specific users only readable to registered users, so search enginges can't see them at all. Trade-off: if a user (which doesn't disallow indexing of his content/name) quotes the text of such a restricted post, it's in the search index again.
- Disallow indexing of the whole page, when such a specific user posted there. Trade-off: no search engine results for this thread
- Anonymize the name of these specific users. Trade-off: community might suffer.

In general, I would try to avoid implementing such a feature (or at least not rely on it). *Either* it is a public board, *or* it is a private board. If it would be required, I'd only allow it for the thread starter. When a user creates a new thread, he is able to select if it's a private or a public thread. If it's a private thread, the whole page will get a `noindex` (or better: permission restriction). All other users get informed whether they are posting on a private or public thread. So if someone wants to stay "private", he'd only post in private threads.

Answer (score 1):

Use `robots.txt` in the root directory of your server to tell bots whether to index or not your website. http://www.robotstxt.org

If you want to hide just a part of the site, you can use `googleon` and `googleoff` tags, follow this: http://perishablepress.com/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/

Also remember that robots.txt is just a guide for bots. It does not physically disallow them, or anyone, to enter your website.

Comment: Hi Miszy, I don't want to hide an entire page, just a section of it.  For example, imagine you have a message board.  You want the site to be index.  But users may not want their postings to show up when others search on Google for their name.  So I am trying to find a way to tell Google to ignore certain <p></p> or <div>

Comment: That is great, thanks Miszy, seems like an easier implementation than the iframe (though I wonder if you'd have to do it for each search engine).

Comment: One way to go used to be using JavaScript to render the content. It's not anymore since now Google Search Appliance is able to interpret JS while crawling http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html I am not aware of any other techniques.

Comment: `googleon`/`googleoff` **does not** work for the usual Google bot/search. It's [only for Google Search Appliance](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/46/admin_crawl/Preparing). So you can't use that to mark parts of your content not to be indexed by Google.